# What is mAP in object detection?

Tags: precision, mean, object-detection

I have been reading through this [blog](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/map-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173) in order to find what **mAP** is .In the sub heading of AP, they give the example of 5 apple images and finding out the average precision.As far I understand `false positive` is when the object is localised and classified but `IOU < 0.5`  (in the blog) and false negative is when the model fails to identify an object itself.So what about objects which are misclassified dont they belong to false postives?.

Also what does the table in the blog really respresent.The `'correct?'` is for one particluar example or 5 examples together.Could you just brief me what is going on in your own terms or just what the blog says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is mAP in object detection?

**mAP** is just **mean average precision** which is the mean of **AP**s from all the object classes. For example, if you had 5 object classes each of them would have an average precision (**AP**) and **mAP** will be the sum of those **AP**s divided by 5.

> false positive is when the object is localized and classified but IOU < 0.5

In object detection, we can have multiple classes of objects. The background is also a class but it is implicit. So for example, if we had 3 classes of objects (e.g. apple, orange, banana) the network considers it as 4 classes (apple, orange, banana, background). Only in the results, the program doesn't draw a bounding box around background objects.

**False Positive** means that the object detection model has reported a part of the image as an object of a specific class (e.g. apple). However, there is no apple in that part of the image. There is either another fruit like an orange (misclassification) or no fruit at all (background). Both cases are the same in the eye of the network and we consider this as false positive. So the network is considering that part as a positive sample for a specific class by mistake. The IoU can have any value in this case (it does not matter). The misclassified objects are also included in the false positive rate because they are reported as positive (for a specific class) but in fact, they are negative (they belong to another class or background).

**False Negative** means the model has predicted a part of the image as background when it is actually an object. In other words, the network has failed to detect an object and has reported it as background by mistake.

> what does the table in the blog really represent?

The **IoU** (Intersection over Union) referred to in the blog which is used to report **correct** is calculated by dividing the area of the intersection between the detected box and the ground truth (the box drawn by a human as the correct box) by the union of those areas.

[image]

So if IoU is more than 0.5, it means that the network has predicted the apple position correctly. In the table, **correct** is for each apple and the precision is calculated from the number of correct predictions divided by all predictions.

Comment: Thank you hadi , it was a great explanation.But can you elaborate what is AP here.There is only precision,how come the word 'average' is introduced here?.Suppose 4 apples were predicted and out of which 2 are correct.So precision = 2/4.Thats all.What is the use of AP that is mentioned in the post? why not just calculate precision?

Comment: The short answer is that **AP** is the area under the precision-recall curve. But the long answer is that **AP** is calculated for each class at each image by averaging the precision values for bounding boxes of different precisions. There are much better explanations [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/breaking-down-mean-average-precision-map-ae462f623a52) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/315216/165527).